# Bootstrap 5 - Spacing для адаптивности

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap, spacing

Пробую учиться с помощью практики на **Bootstrap 5** и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: для адаптивности сайта использую классы с колонками: `сol-lg, col-md` и т. д., но также использовал и **spacing** например: `mt-2, pe-2`, это было намного проще и удобнее для меня в написании страницы сайта.
Вопрос в следующем: в документации **Spacing** явно говорится, что масштабировать их нельзя, но когда меняются размеры сайта то подходящее `mt-2` для `lg` уже не подходит для `md`.
Чтобы это исправить мне придётся прописывать `@media` внутри каждого класса: mt, pe или это можно сделать проще?

Answer (score 0):

> The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, xl, and xxl.

т.е. вы можете указать отступы для разных размеров, например

```
mt-3-lg mt-2-md mt-1
```

При изменени размера экрана применится соответствующий margin